# two-stage user activation from database

Tags: database, users

I'm trying to create a system where, say for a school or other organizations, I can load a ton of users into a database at once, so that they are grouped separately from other databases of users. However, I then want it so that when the user logs in for the first time, it will ask them to fill in all the remaining fields that aren't loaded from the original database, such as a password and email.

is there an easy way to do a two-stage user creation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Always best to include the Drupal version you are making use of, for the purpose of the answer will assume its Drupal 7;

So there are two parts to this;

1) The user data upload to drupal; you could make use of the [Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) module; I would think in the very least you would need to set the username and a temporary password to facilitate the first time login instance.

2) To force the user to fill in his details you could make use of the [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) in a custom module implementation to validate that the user's details have been filled in.